# Ubuntu boots to grub terminal

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I have a dual boot laptop with Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows XP. I Normally use Ubuntu, and I hadn't gone to windows in a long time, so I wanted to test it. After I was done, I restarted the laptop to get to Ubuntu. When I selected it in the menu where you choose you're OS, it went to a terminal thing that said "grub" and some instructions. I have no idea how to get to my desktop so that I can do things, so is there any command I can use?

Sorry that I'm a bit bad at using Linux :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should run a [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) via a live CD/DVD or USB drive. That should fix up your GRUB bootloader.